# Do not create URL link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, helper

**app/vies/items/show.html.erb**

```
    <h1><%= @item.name %></h1>

<ul>
    <li><%= @item.price %> руб.</li>
    <li><%= urls_to_images(@item.description) %></li>
    <li>Вес: <%= @item.weight %> кг.</li>
</ul>
```

**app/helpers/application_helper.rb**

```
    module ApplicationHelper

  def urls_to_images(s)
    s.gsub! /\s(http:\/\/.*?)/ , '<img src="\1"/>'
    s.html_safe
  end

  # def urls_to_links(s)
  # 
  # end

end
```

**browser interface :**

[image]

**Displayed text. Why not output link?**

Comment: What is the HTML you expect to be rendered, and what HTML is being rendered?

Comment: Yes, but I have found the answer, sorry for the stupid question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def urls_to_images(s)
    s.gsub! /\s(http:\/\/.*?)(\s|\Z)/ , '<img src="\1"/>'
    s.html_safe
  end
```

**now works **

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you did mistake in `urls_to_images` method. try this -

```
 def urls_to_images(s)
   s = s.gsub! /\s(http:\/\/.*?)/ , '<img src="\1"/>'
   s.html_safe
 end
```

Comment: ok @VitalikAndrysha......So, you found answer now. Please answer it and finish this question.

Comment: regular expression was misspelled